# Javascript insert item into correct position in array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I would like to insert an object into a sorted array of objects, but to know at which position to insert it :)

I have the following array of objects, the array is sorted by IP field:

```
let array = [{ 'ip': '192.168.0.1' }, { 'ip': '192.168.0.4'}, { 'ip': '192.168.0.10'}, { 'ip': '192.168.0.50'}, { 'ip': '192.168.0.60'}, ];
```

Now I would like to insert a new object to the array:

```
const newObject = { ip: '192.168.0.13' };
```

How can I add this new object to the correct position?

So that my array then looks like:

```
 let array = [{ 'ip': '192.168.0.1' }, { 'ip': '192.168.0.4'}, { 'ip': '192.168.0.10'}, { ip: '192.168.0.13' }, { 'ip': '192.168.0.50'}, { 'ip': '192.168.0.60'}, ];
```

How could I find the correct index, where to insert the item ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another answer using `findIndex` and `splice` but with a different way to compare the IP-addresses.

By converting them into a single 32bit number. imo. simpler to deal with than an array of 4 bytes.

```js
let array = [
  { 'ip': '192.168.0.1'}, 
  { 'ip': '192.168.0.4'}, 
  { 'ip': '192.168.0.10'}, 
  { 'ip': '192.168.0.50'},
  { 'ip': '192.168.0.60'},
]; 

const newObject = { ip: '192.168.0.13' };

const foldIp = (a,b) => a<<8 | b;
const ipValue = item => item.ip.split(".").reduce(foldIp, 0);

const newObjectValue = ipValue(newObject);
const index = array.findIndex(item => ipValue(item) > newObjectValue);

if (index === -1) {
  array.push(newObject);
} else {
  array.splice(index, 0, newObject);
}

console.log(array);

// or use it to sort();
console.log(
  "sort descending:", // as the array is currently sorted ascending
  array.sort((a,b) => ipValue(b) - ipValue(a))
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

#### Added both conversions

```
const IP = {
  // 3232235521 -> '192.168.0.1'
  toString(value) {
    return `${value >>> 24}.${value >> 16 & 0xFF}.${value >> 8 & 0xFF}.${value & 0xFF}`
  },
  // '192.168.0.1' -> 3232235521
  toUint(value) {
    const arr = value.split(".");
    return (arr[0] << 24 | arr[1] << 16 | arr[2] << 8 | arr[3]) >>> 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `splice` and set the delete count to `0` to add at a specific position but this would *mutate* the original array.

The same can be done with `slice` and spread operator but it would not mutate the original array.

To find the exact position where you need to insert, you can pass a predicate to the `findIndex` function. The `findIndex` function would the right index where you need to insert the new object.

The predicate here would be an IP comparison function. In my example I made a crude IP comparing function which does the job:

```js
let array = [{ 'ip': '192.168.0.1' }, { 'ip': '192.168.0.4'}, { 'ip': '192.168.0.10'}, { 'ip': '192.168.0.50'}, { 'ip': '192.168.0.60'}, ]; 
const newObject = { ip: '192.168.0.13' };

const compareIp = (ip1, ip2) => {
  const arr1 = ip1.split(".").map(n => +n);
  const arr2 = ip2.split(".").map(n => +n);
  return arr1.every((e, i) => e <= arr2[i]);
}

//Not mutating original array
const insertAtPosition = (arr, obj) => {
  const idx = arr.findIndex(o =>  compareIp(obj.ip, o.ip));
  return [...array.slice(0, idx), obj,...array.slice(idx)]
}

//Mutating original array
const insertAtPositionMutated = (arr, obj) => {
   const idx = arr.findIndex(o =>  compareIp(obj.ip, o.ip));
  arr.splice(idx, 0, obj);
  return arr
}

console.log(insertAtPosition(array, newObject));

console.log(insertAtPositionMutated(array, newObject));
```

Comment: I know about that, but what if I have a bigger list, I would want to find at which position to insert item ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
array.push(newObject);
```

And after that sort it again.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Array.findIndex`, you can find the position to be inserted into the current array and using `Array.splice`, you can insert ip address to that position.

```js
let array = [{ 'ip': '192.168.0.1' }, { 'ip': '192.168.0.4'}, { 'ip': '192.168.0.10'}, { 'ip': '192.168.0.50'}, { 'ip': '192.168.0.60'}, ]; 
const newObject = { ip: '192.168.0.13' };

const newIpArr = newObject.ip.split(".").map(item => parseInt(item));
const insertPos = array.findIndex(({ ip }) => {
  const ipArr = ip.split(".").map(item => parseInt(item));
  for (let index = 0; index < ipArr.length; index ++) {
    if (ipArr[index] > newIpArr[index]) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
});
array.splice(insertPos, 1, newObject);
console.log(array);
```